# Unable to list the tables from MS SQL using SQOOP

Tags: hive, sqoop

I tried to list the databases in MS SQL using the sqoop command

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:sqlserver://10.x.x.x --username my_usrnme --password my_pwd
```

It worked correctly listing all the databases in SQL server.

But when I tried to list the tables in a specific database using the command

```
sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:sqlserver://10.x.x.x/db_name --username my_usrnme --password my_pwd
```

I am getting the error as

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the  host 10.x.x.x/db_name, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the
>   connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the  host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is 
>   blocking TCP connections to the port."

Has any one faced this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My query worked after changing the command slightly as

```
sqoop list-tables --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://10.x.x.x;database=db_name' --username my_usrnme --password my_pwd
```

Whats required is, servername and dbname has to be in  ' '(single quotes) and separated by ; (semi-colon).

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to connect to the Db from sqoop?

First, verify that you can connect to the database from the node where you are running Sqoop:

```
$ mysql --host=<IP Address> --database=test --user=<username> --password=<password>
```

If this doesn't work then you will have to consider fixing  client network configuration